# Why is UIControlTouchUpInside UNDEFINED?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uicontrol

I've got a simple question but it has got me confounded. The code below gets an UNDEFINED error for UIControlTouchUpInside. What do I need to include or import? If I comment out the line, it works. So that means forState:UIControlStateNormal is defined. I'm new so hope you can help.

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Accept?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(acceptTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to import anything. You need only consult the documentation, where you will find that the symbol you're looking for is `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. You could also just type "UIControl" in XCode and hit escape. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` will be in the list that pops up.